# Add active flag to AuthComponent's login sequence

Tags: cakephp

What's the best practice to add a simple active flag to a user record that the AuthComponent will respect during the login sequence?  I have a simple boolean field in my user table.  That flag needs to be set to allow the user to login.  Otherwise, they get the normal "You can't login" error.

I've googled around and can't find any good examples of how to add this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, I use the following line of code in my `app_controller`:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array ( 'Administrator.active' => '1' );
```

In my case, the `userModel` is `Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I tried the answer above in the `AppController->beforeFilter` but it doesn't work. In my case, the model is User, so I put:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array ( 'User.active' => '1' );
```